# How to complete correctly a branched pipeline with BatchBlock?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Consider the following pipeline:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var firstBlock = new TransformBlock<string, string>(s =>
    {
         Console.WriteLine("FirstBlock");
         return s + "-FirstBlock";
    });
    var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<string>(100, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { Greedy = true });
    var afterBatchBlock = new TransformManyBlock<string[], string>(strings =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AfterBatchBlock");
        return new[] { strings[0] + "-AfterBatchBlock" };
    });
    var lastBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(s =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"LastBlock {s}");
    });
    firstBlock.LinkTo(batchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }, x => x.Contains("0"));
    batchBlock.LinkTo(afterBatchBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        
    afterBatchBlock.LinkTo(lastBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        firstBlock.LinkTo(lastBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    firstBlock.Post("0");

    firstBlock.Complete();
    firstBlock.Completion.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    batchBlock.Completion.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    afterBatchBlock.Completion.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    lastBlock.Completion.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Running this code gets blocked with the following output:

> FirstBlock
> AfterBatchBlock

What I think is happening behind the scenes is the following:

- FirstBlock sends a Completion signal to all its linked targets (BatchBlock, AfterBatchBlock, LastBlock)
- BatchBlock and LastBlock gets completed
- AfterBatchBlock then tries to pass its output to LastBlock but it is already completed and it gets stuck forever.

My question is:

1. Is it a bug?
2. Assuming it is by design, what is the recommended way to overcome the bad state my pipeline reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. This is the expected behavior. You must first realize that you are not dealing with a simple, straightforward dataflow pipeline, but rather with a dataflow mesh. It's not a complex mesh, but still not what I would describe as pipeline. Dealing with the completion of dataflow blocks that form a mesh can be tricky. In your case you have one block, the `lastBlock`, which is the target of two source blocks, the `firstBlock` and `afterBatchBlock`. This block should be completed when **both** source blocks have completed, not **either one** them. So you can't use the `PropagateCompletion = true` option when linking this block with its sources.

There is no built-in API to do this, but implementing a two-to-one completion propagator is not very difficult. In fact you could just copy-paste the `PropagateCompletion` method found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63748814/many-to-many-tpl-dataflow-does-not-process-all-inputs/63749571#63749571), and use it like this:

```
afterBatchBlock.LinkTo(lastBlock);
firstBlock.LinkTo(lastBlock);

PropagateCompletion(new IDataflowBlock[] { afterBatchBlock, firstBlock },
    new[] { lastBlock });
```